# How do you include adsense javascript inside another javascript code

Tags: javascript

How do I add adsense code to this javascript code. I think there might be a solution with jquery and getscript, but I'm not able to get it to work

```
<script>
var rep = $("#topbar").find(".reputation-score").text().replace(/,|\s/g,'');
if (rep.match(/\d+k/i)) rep = rep.replace(/k/g, '') * 1000;
if (rep == "") rep = 0;
if (rep < 200 && $("#banner-bottom").length == 0) {
  if ($(".answer").length == 0)
    abovebanner = $("#answers-header");
  else
    abovebanner = $(".answer:first");
  abovebanner.after('HELP ADD ADSENSE CODE HERE');
}
</script>
```

and guys I'm not very good with javascript, so if you guys could paste a working solution. I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://javascript.about.com/library/bladdjs.htm) explains a method to do this. Once you have created the wrapper function (addJavascript) mentioned on that page added, your last line would like something like:

```
addJavascript('adsense-library-name.js','head');
```

The implementation of addJavascript (from the page above):

```
function addJavascript(jsname,pos) {
  var th = document.getElementsByTagName(pos)[0];
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
  s.setAttribute('src',jsname);
  th.appendChild(s);
}
```

Comment: Please provide an answer here, in part at the very least.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: Who do you mean, the OP?